# android the image looks too small on screen, how to scale it to fit the screen? wrap_content does not seem to work

Tags: android, imageview

android the image looks too small on screen, how to scale it to fit the screen? wrap_content does not seem to work

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"/>
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use the DynamicImageView class explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992535/android-imageview-scale-smaller-image-to-width-with-flexible-height-without-crop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your ImageView to get it to scale as you like (will fill the size of your ImageView):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

I would actually change your width attribute as well.  Your final XML could look like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"/>
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. The image extends to left edge of the screen as expected, but not to right, above and below.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, the following works:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's your image issue,may be the image contains unnecessarily enlarged background,crop the image,remove unnecessary background and then it will be solved