# Crop Imageview using input Specific Length and width

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I have app. I want to crop my picture that shown in imageview. I want crop with spesific length and width. can you help me? I have code but, that code crop direct from gallery.

I just want crop imageview with spesific length and width. Where length and width just input manual from user.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992535/android-imageview-scale-smaller-image-to-width-with-flexible-height-without-crop

Comment: No.... i am not to do centercrop. i want the length and width that input manual by user. just like input with inputbox on Java. can this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a new Library to your project just to do image loading for you, you can easily add Glide to crop your local drawables or images from the web.

In your build.gradle (module app)

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
```

You can crop the image with this below:

```
 final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

        final int myWidth = 210;
        final int myHeight = 80;
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.example_drawable) // you can add any drawable or url of an image here
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                        // Do something with bitmap here.
                        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                });
```